# Using Custom Zend Validator in INI file

Tags: php, zend-framework, ini, customvalidator

I don't have a custom Zend_Form and I just declared all the elements in the ini file. There is no problem with creating the Zend_Form from the ini file, but I am having problem using my own custom validator in my ini file. It always return Not Found In Registry error.

Currently, my code is like this.

```
[Bootstrap]

$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'namespace' => 'MY',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__)
        ));

$resourceLoader->addResourceType('validator', 'forms/validate/', 'Form_Validate');

[ini file]
form.elements.new_password.options.validators.password.validator = "Password"

[Custom Validator]
<?php 

class MY_Form_Validate_Password extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
......
```

Please tell me what I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: I believe your ini reference is correct... I think you just need to change `MY` to `MY_` in your namespace value in the Resource autoloader

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer my question. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: try adding the _ to the end of Form_Validate in the addResourceType call

Comment: again thank you, but it's still not working. :(

Comment: do you have the `My_` namespace specified in your autoloaderNamespaces in the ini? `autoloaderNamespaces.My = My_` and the path leading to the the My directories parent path in the include path?

Comment: it's actually working for other resource types except validator.

Comment: So just so I understand the lay of the land. Relative to the folder containing the bootstrap file you have a file located at `forms/validate/Password.php" that contains the class described in the OP? What is the exact verbiage of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of over thinking:

I'm going to assume you're using a version of ZF1.x that's fairly new (v1.10 and newer).

You have a file called `project/application/configs/application.ini`

in a standard application.ini is the line:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

this tells us that all of our library code (a custom validator qualifies) would belong to the directory at this path.

Also there is the line:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MY_"
```

This tells us the name of our library (defines the directory below /library).

so our custom validator `MY_Form_Validate_Password` would live at:

```
project
    /library
        /MY 
            /Form
                /Validate
                    Password.php
```

nothing else is required, all that bootstrap code is only needed if you are going to do something not anticipated by Zend Framework, also validators are not typically registered as resources.

The class can be called as

```
$validator = new MY_Form_Validate_Password();
```

as usual and any other access method should work as well.

Comment: thank you @RockyFord. What if I'm going to call it from the ini file?

Comment: .ini files are your business, the validator should be accessible no matter which method is used to call it. Once the file is available to the autoloader every method of access should work.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But, I am not using a custom Form class here so everything is written in my ini file.